# Why won't MySQL create any rows after importing the database?

Tags: mysql, database, import, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import a database that is 8.77 MB in size via phpMyAdmin and it says that the import was successful but it only creates the tables without any rows. [Tables generated without any data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q8pb.png)

I'm not using cmd or anything like that to import the database, I'm simply using the Import option at the top of the page in phpMyAdmin, selecting the file and clicking "Import". It takes about 10 seconds to load but it generates 4 tables without any rows.

I've tried importing the zip file as specified (dbname.sql.zip) but it says that the compression is not supported, so I am uploading the uncompressed sql file. I also tried importing the database several times, refreshing, restarting XAMPP and nothing has worked. I even checked to make sure that the file I was uploading even had anything in it.

phpMyAdmin is not showing me any errors at all. It says:

**Import has been successfully finished, 26 queries executed. (mexico.sql)**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following Points:

1. Check File: Make sure your SQL file isn't corrupted.
2. Check File Size Limit: Servers and PHP configurations often have limits on file uploads. Check your php.ini file for upload_max_filesize and post_max_size. If your file is larger, might need to increase these limits.
   Also, phpMyAdmin has its own settings in config.inc.php that you can check.
3. Upload File without Compression: If compression is causing trouble, unzip the SQL file manually and try to import the uncompressed .sql file instead.
4. Check Error Reporting Will Help: check for error messages or warnings during the import process in phpMyAdmin. These messages usually give clues about what's going wrong.